# Trying to retrieve mail information using pop3 from "fake smtp server"

Tags: linux, smtp, imap, pop3

I have 3 virtual machines:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.44 (server)
xxx.xxx.xxx.55 (send mails)
xxx.xxx.xxx.66 (read mails)
```

For the server, I have this line:

```
python3 -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n  XXX.XXX.XXX.44:25
```

to host the "smtp server"

When i use xxx.xxx.xxx.55 to send an email using a python code, I am able to get this result:

---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------

```
b'From:john@emailserver.com'

b'To:Robert@emailserver.com'

b'Date:03/01/2023 15:45:06'

b'Subject:lol'

b'X-Peer: XXX.XXX.XXX.55'

b''

b'lol'
```

------------ END MESSAGE ------------

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve this "message" using pop/imap on xxx.xxx.xxx.66

It would also help if anyone knows where this "message" is stored on the email server so that I could use poplib to retrieve this message.

Comment: I have trying to simulate an SMTP and POP protocol without using any actual servers, if anyone has any suggestions on how else I can do this I am open to suggestions thanks :)

Comment: The smtpd library does whatever you would _like_ it to do with the message.  You need to implement `process_message` and then do something with it.  There's no easy popd or imapd support.  Why not install a trivial mail server (dovecot/courier/etc.) and use that?